# Teclado español en los navegadores

Tags: linux, debian, google-chrome, firefox, opera

Después de una actualización de Debian v.10 me ha sucedido que en los navegadores, tanto Chrome, Firefox u Opera, he perdido el teclado español en los navegadores pero sin embargo en el SO sí está bien configurado porque escribo en el terminal y sigo manteniendo las tildes y la eñe sin problema.

He buscado en la configuración de los navegadores y está marcada la opción de teclado Español pero de ninguna manera.

No sé si se me está escapando otra forma de configurar el teclado que tenga en común todos los navegadores.

¿A alguien más le ha pasado?

Comment: No sé si se configurará igual en Debian que en Ubuntu, pero en "Región e Idioma", si tienes varias fuentes de entrada (te recomiendo tener únicamente la de "Español" y quitar otras distribuciones de teclado) te aparecerá un botón de "Opciones" que te permite habilitar el soporte para configurar la fuente de entrada por aplicación (es decir, una distribución de teclado diferente por cada aplicación). Tanto activo como no, al tener varias fuentes de entrada te aparece un panel con la selección de la distribución de teclado para poder cambiarla. ¿Puedes confirmar que tengas algo de todo esto?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Oscar.

Efectivamente ya tengo solo el Español como único idioma en la fuente de entrada, incluso en las opciones de idioma y formatos también el único que tengo es Español y España.

Lo extraño es que en la terminal si me los reconozca pero en ninguno de los navegadores lo haga. No sé que parte común de los navegadores estará trastocada que será la que haya que modificar.

Comment: Te recomiendo instalar una nueva distribución de teclado (la que sea) para que aparezca la opción que te comento y el panel de idioma. Desactivar la opción de distribución de teclado por aplicación (si estaba activada), abrir los navegadores y ver qué lenguaje o distribución muestra el panel de idioma para ponerla en español si era diferente (o cambiar al nuevo y volver a español para forzar el cambio). Por último, volver a eliminar la distribución de teclado que has agregado para esta prueba y comprobar que todo quedó correcto.

Comment: Muchas gracias @OscarGarcia, lo volví a rehacer todo. Modifiqué la configuración para luego volver a ponerle Español y me funcionó correctamente. 

Me quedo con la curiosidad de saber qué sucedió pero me sirvió tu comentario para solucionarlo. Gracias de nuevo por tu tiempo.

Comment: No tengo ni idea de por qué ocurre, pero me han pasado cosas similares en versiones anteriores que he usado de Ubuntu (ahora cada vez que actualizo de versión hago instalación limpia, pero antes pasaba de una versión a otra actualizando y siempre terminaba perdiendo el tiempo arreglando algo). Con cosas de la distribución del teclado he batallado ¡incluso en Windows! xD aunque nunca me pasó durante una actualización normal, sólo en subidas de versión. Me alegra que lo solucionaras.

Comment: PD; si quieres redacta una respuesta explicando cómo lo solucionaste. Es posible que le sea de utilidad a alguien en un futuro. Tendrás mi voto.

Comment: Ya ni por el voto, si no tiene todo el sentido del mundo la idea de redactar la respuesta, si no es como dejar este hilo incompleto, me pongo a ello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues al final mi solución fue la de seleccionar idioma, formato y fuente de entrada en inglés, guardar y luego volver a entrar para seleccionar Español y España como se ve en la imagen en todas las opciones.

No sé exactamente qué pudo ser pero sirvió para volver a setear la configuración en Español.

Me pasó lo mismo en otro ordenador con mismo Debian pero no sé si tuvo que ver con la insatalación de un programa en concreto, que fue el AnyDesk, pero esto último es una hipótesis.

[image: Configuración / Región e idioma]

Answer (score 0):

Mismo problema, pero no se solucionaba ni cambiando el idioma. Desinstalé Anydesk y dependencias y al reiniciar volvió a la normalidad.

sudo apt-get remove anydesk && sudo apt autoremove